# list indices must be integers or slices, not dict - in specified case?

Tags: python-3.x

first time i post question on stack ! I'd like to go straight into my problem !

> Line 114 : error list indices must be integers or slices, not dict

This line got error(I bolded the full code below) :

```py
if dist[c]>=dist[v]+dataAry[v][c]:
```

I just need give some solutions for this error, the majority of code worked as i wish, so i have to write some more sentences that stack allow me to post

```py
dataJustified="{:>3}"

dataAry = {
  0: [{1: 5}, {2: 4}, {5: 5}],
  1: [{3: 3}],
  2: [{7: 6}],
  3: [{8: 8}],
  4: [{8: 4}],
  5: [{4: 2}, {6: 4}, {9: 3}],
  6: [{7: 7}, {10: 5}],
  7: [],
  8: [{9: 7}],
  9: [],
  10: [],
}

print("Display Dijkstra's algorithm Shortest Path")
dist=[]
prev=[]
s=0
v=0
vl=[]

for c in range(len(dataAry)):
    if c==0:
        dist.append(0)
        prev.append(-1)
    else:
        dist.append(999)
        prev.append(0)

while len(vl)!=len(dataAry)-1:
    vl.append(v)
    u=[]
    del u[:]
    for index in dataAry[v]:
        u.append(index)
    for c in u:
        if dist[c]>=dist[v]+dataAry[v][c]:
            dist[c]=dist[v]+dataAry[v][c]
            prev[c]=v

    new_dist = dist[:]
    for x in vl:
        new_dist.remove(dist[x])

    minV = min(new_dist)

    if dist.index(minV) not in vl:
        v = dist.index(minV)
    else:
        new_dist_2 = dist[:]
        new_dist_2[dist.index(minV)] = 999
        v = new_dist_2.index(minV)

print("dist : ", dist)
print("prev : ", prev)
```

Comment: What do you with with this script? 
c in dist[c] is a dict as error says.

Comment: I want to compare the lens between 2 linked nodes as describe in my dict ! Output will be a shortest path from nodes 1 to nodes 2 : example from 0--5 distance : 5, that is